# Inverse interface

Tags: java, uml

I'm writing a Java program which separates user interface from program logic (I want to have different user interfaces)
So i want to have guaranteed, that there are capabilities to use some features of my program. Especially that means i have a class with some functions and i want to have a guarantee, that these functions will be executed (Or at least, that they somewhere are called).

To be more concrete:
I'm writing a Roguelike in Java and there shall be a classical terminal interface (only using keys) an a windowed interface (with mouse supply). In program logic there is a function for opening doors. Now i want to have guaranteed that in all user interfaces the command to open a door won't be forgotten without compiler errors. Somehow i want to have something like an inverse interface :D
Is there a way?

(An explanation in UML instead Java would be good too)

Comment: There are static analysis tools that may help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Here you had met some discrepancy in words. What you name interfaces, they are User Interfaces, UI, and they'll be realized as classes. Not interfaces.

And those descriptions that will make your UI to have all functionalities needed are called Interfaces. Funny, isn't it? :-)

```
public interface DoorView{
    void openDoor(Orientation: openingDirection);
}
...
public class WinDoorView implements DoorView{ // this line will be marked 
      //as erroneous until you will write the function openDoor for the class

}
public class AsciiDoorView implements DoorView{ 
    void openDoor(Orientation: openingDirection){
        //graphics realization
    }
}
```

[image]

In your conceptual part you'll work with DoorView.

And a class based on the interface MUST have all its functions - it will be controlled by compiler.